# Why super() returns the newly created object in es6?

Tags: ecmascript-6

As far as I know

> The super([arguments]) keyword calls the parent constructor

Having these basic classes:

```
class X{
    constructor(){
       return 'x'; // doesn't matter when calling super()
    }
}
class Z extends X{
    constructor(){
        console.log('This will return the newly created object invoked by new keyword', super())
    }
}
new Z; // Z {}
```

why `super()` return the brand new ***Z*** object?

Comment: What else did you expect?

Comment: @Bergi maybe undefined? ...what's the reason behind it?

Comment: Yeah, `undefined` might have worked as well, but it just returns the `this` value that it just initialised.

Answer (score 2):

You can't return primitive types from constructor.

```js
class X{
    constructor(){
       // to set correct prototype
       return Object.setPrototypeOf(new String("x"), new.target.prototype); 
       // or 
       // return new String('x') just to show you could return any object
    }
}
class Z extends X{
    constructor(){
        console.log('This will return the newly created object invoked by new keyword', super())
    }
}
console.log(new Z); // Z {}
```

Comment: You should `return Object.setPrototypeOf(new String("x"), new.target.prototype)` though

Comment: ok, I got that, but my main question is why? what is the reason for this behaviour? even if the parent constructor does not returns anything, it will still return my new object

Comment: @BarbuBarbu This is how `new` keyword is implemented in js. `var x = new Ctor` is roughly equivalent to `tmp =Object.create(Ctor.prototype); tmp2 = Ctor.apply(tmp); var x = typeof tmp2 === 'object' ? tmp2 : tmp` It checks for what constructor returns. If it is something of object type it is used as the result. Otherwise newly created object is returned.

Comment: I know that, but if you run my code in console you will see that Z {} will be returned twice, once by the new keyword, and second by the super() call

Comment: @BarbuBarbu Well, `super()` inside constructor calls parent constructor. If the later returns then `super` call would do as well. You could check [transpiled to ES5 code](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&targets=Node-8&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEAa0G8BQ1rAPYDsIBcBOArsDungBQCUiKq0eApjgXpopmALb0Bc0A5AA8-AXxqjRSUJBgAtaPQE56mACYx4yVBmz4iJclU21tEdCHoA6EOgDmZCAQAO9AxTFIJJs5et3M9AHdoGQogA) to get a better understanding. Pay attention to `_possibleConstructorReturn`